# How can I create a HashMap that dynamically calls other Java classes?

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a `HashMap<Integer, Class>`, and am not being successful. Essentially, all I want to do is have the ability to dynamically load the classes into the Map.

My managed Bean looks like this:

```
package Demo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author kbarnett
 */
@Named(value = "facePalmBean")
@Dependent
public class FacePalmBean {

    private HashMap<Integer, Class> chimpanzee;
    private NewClass0 NewClass0;
    private NewClass1 NewClass1;
    private NewClass2 NewClass2;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of FacePalmBean
     */
    public FacePalmBean() {

        chimpanzee = new HashMap<>();
        NewClass0 = new NewClass0(0);
        NewClass1 = new NewClass1(1);
        NewClass2 = new NewClass2(2);

    }

    public HashMap<Integer, Class> getChimpanzee() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                String tmpstring = "NewClass"+i;
                System.out.println(tmpstring);
                Class tmpclass = Class.forName(tmpstring);
                System.out.println(tmpclass);
                chimpanzee.put(i, tmpclass);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FacePalmBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(chimpanzee.toString());
        return chimpanzee;
    }

    public void setChimpanzee(HashMap<Integer,Class> chimpanzee) {
        this.chimpanzee=chimpanzee;
    }


}
```

and the NewClasses look like this:

```
package Demo;


public class NewClass0 {
        Integer MyNumber;

    NewClass0(int num){
        MyNumber=num;
    }

    public Integer getMyNumber() {
        return MyNumber;
    }
}
```

All of the NewClasses are identical except for the number (i.e. 0, 1, and 2).

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to accomplish here? This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I was just trying to load classes into a HashMap; Chris Thompson explained it perfectly, and my code is working now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to load a class with the `Class.forName()` method, you must specify a fully qualified package name.  In this case it must be `Demo.NewClass0`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for preserving my sanity!